# Replace windows 8 with windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

Yesterday, I got my windows 8 BSoD on boot (reboot repeatedly) for "system thread exception not handled" so I can't do anything thus I installed ubuntu 12.04. still, I prefer windows for compatibilities sake...

But now I want to replace the windows 8 with windows 7 64bit ultimate. So, how to remove the windows 8 from my laptop using ubuntu because I still can't access windows 8 directly(still BSoD) and install windows 7 then?

Comment: do you have Windows on a separate disk?

Comment: yeah then just wipe the other disk in Ubuntu and install windows 7 on it.

Comment: This is a bit weird. I mean, to come on Ubuntu Q&A site and ask "how can I replace Windows 8 with Windows 7". Better would be to ask this question on a Windows Q&A site-forum.

Comment: Yeah is kinda :P

Comment: Has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Fix lies in using a bootable installation or recovery media (that can be any OS).

Comment: You can use GParted from an Ubuntu LiveCD to re-format your Windows 8 installation.. that is, if you can get the LiveCD to boot. Otherwise just use your Windows 7 installation media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GParted to format the separate disk.

first you have to install GParted :

open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl + alt + T</kbd>

Then enter the following: `sudo apt-get install gparted` and wait until the installation is complete. After that type in the terminal `sudo gparted` and hit enter.

A window should open.

Follow the instructions in the link: [Format a disk using GParted](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17001/how-to-format-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-using-gparted/)

**Update:**

My Tutorial:

- Open GParted in a terminal with `sudo gparted`
- In the upper right corner you can choose the HDD [image: gparted]
  [image]
- Choose the HDD where Windows 8 is installed on.
- Right click on the HDD (like in the foto) and choose `Format to` and then the File System you want it formatted in. I would recomend you format it in NTFS. [image]
- After that there will popup a field at the bottom saying Format "Path" as NTFS. Right click and press `Apply all Operations`. [image]
- Press Apply. [image]
- Wait for the Operation to finish and your done. Your disk is formatted. [image]